# How to catch all stripe webhook events that are not explicitly handled?

Tags: django, stripe-payments, webhooks

There are a lot of different types of [Stripe events](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types). Further, they note they can add more at any time. I am using dj-stripe. With my event handlers I have an OK idea of what types of webhooks I should be monitoring for a pretty straightforward Stripe subscription setup. Within the dj-stripe framework is there an easy way to catch unhandled webhooks that I encounter in production? On these I'd like to email myself that an unhandled Stripe webhook event has occurred.

For example, I have the following webhook handlers:

```
@csrf_exempt
@webhooks.handler("checkout")
def my_handler(event, **kwargs):
    print("handling checkout event...")
    print(event.type)

@csrf_exempt
@webhooks.handler("customer")
def my_customer_handler(event, **kwargs):
    print("handling customer event... in my_customer_handler")
    print(event.type)

@csrf_exempt
@webhooks.handler("charge")
def my_charge_handler(event, **kwargs):
    print("handling charge event... in my_charge_handler")
    print(event.type)

@csrf_exempt
@webhooks.handler("payment_intent")
def my_payment_intent_handler(event, **kwargs):
    print("handling payment_intent event... in my_payment_intent_handler")
    print(event.type)


@csrf_exempt
@webhooks.handler("price", "product")
def my_price_and_product_handler(event, **kwargs):
    print("handling price/product event... in my_price_and_product_handler")
    print(event.type)
```

Now let's say that some type of invoice webhook comes in. I understand that djstripe will save this event to the `djstripe_invoice` table (via `path('stripe/', include("djstripe.urls", namespace="djstripe")),`). But what if I want to catch that it not a webhook type that is currently handled outside of the built-in dj-stripe URLs? Is there any webhook signature I can add to notify me that a webhook event has occurred that I didn't do anything on other than update the DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stripe recommends [only subscribing to events necessary for your business](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/best-practices#event-types), so if you did discover subscribed events you aren't handling a good option would be to unsubscribe from them.

If you want to do some processing for *all* events, it looks like `dj-stripe` has a `handler_all` option ([code](https://github.com/dj-stripe/dj-stripe/blob/master/djstripe/webhooks.py#L57)). You'd likely want to maintain some dictionary of explicit event types you handle and check if the received event is handled before logging your unhandled event.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer @Nolan. I might need to clarify, how do I know which events I should be subscribing to? And how to I differentiate between an event I am not handling that I should be listening to and an event I should not be listening to nor handling?

Comment: For the second part, it's a bit trcky because of how djstripe handles groups of event types. I think you'd maintain a list of the events your various handlers cover and check the types against that list. As for which you should subscribe to, it really depends on what you're trying to achieve. Every integration is different. Stripes docs for various scenarios will specify when individual events are recommended, but the right ones for you is not a one-size-fits-all answer.

Comment: That was the jist I was getting from the docs (kind of "it depends") but they do touch on the bare minimum events to monitor for in subscriptions and things like that. Your answer will help me catch anything I'm not handling (esp. outside new customers) so upvoted & accepted. Thx.